# Spring boot Jar to war [classmate-1.3.3.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)]

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jar, war

I am trying to change my spring application packaging mode from jar to war file. (with maven)

I followed the step described in
**Packaging executable jar and war files**
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging & 
**Create a deployable war file**
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

But when I drop my war file in apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps, I have the following error :

```
    1-May-2017 10:05:59.051 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer$1
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Dev\apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps\palmyramobappcomponentservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\classmate-1.3.3.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2633)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:849)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1395)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The path and the jar are there

PS : I have not issue with the jar execution

Tks for you help

Nico

Comment: I got the exact same issue. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on error, classmate jar is not available in your generated war file. Add the below dependency tag if already not available.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The classmate jar is available in my war file :-(

Comment: @NICO did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be helpful to anyone but I saw the same error in Tomcat's localhost log.

Turns out it was only happening when I was undeploying my application by deleting both the war file and the unzipped directory with its contents at the same time from Tomcat's webapps folder.